Blindfold Simultaneous software
Is there any chess software out there that will let one play blind and simultaneous?  I really don't want to find guinea pigs for a couple of reasons, but I do want to learn how to play more than one game at at time blind.
I think there's software that can be voice enabled - so it would allow for blind play.  What about software that would allow more than one board like this?

lichess has blind simul option

meant to say you can make the board settings blinfold and do a normal simul

You can change the piece settings to Blindfolded on lichess and chess.com and play normal simul games. Here's how you can change it on lichess: Go to the Game Page and click on the three stripes in the top-right.

and for chesscom, go to settings page -> Board -> Pieces:

